# How to launch GUI app (in Ctrl+Alt+F7) from tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6)

Tags: command-line, display, tty

I want to know that how can I launch GUI apps from tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>) into GUI mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

Sometimes, users having problem with GUI mode like: can login to GUI but Launcher is not working or unable to open even terminal from shortcut. Then this can help to launch essential applications from tty

Comment: If you already have a running X session, what's the point of dropping to a tty and launching an app from there? That sounds like asking how to swim after attaching a rock to your foot, why attach the rock in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify **`DISPLAY`** environment to specify display for launching apps (see [Graphical Environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Graphical_desktop-related_variables)) as follows from tty:

```
DISPLAY=:0 <app-command>
```

Example:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gedit
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal
```

**This will launch GUI applications in GUI mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) from tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>)**.